# Como converter direcao (bearing) em azimute usando python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Sou iniciante em python.
Li um arquivo excel, criei um dataframe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gerei uma coluna com o quadrante(string) e outra contendo os graus

```
df['DIRECAO'] = df['DIRECAO'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df['quadrante'] = df['DIRECAO'].str[0] + df['DIRECAO'].str[-1]
df['graus'] = df['DIRECAO'].str[1:-1].astype(float) 
df.head()
```

Dataframe

```
PROF_med    PROF_vert   INCL    DIRECAO quadrante   graus
0   5.0     5.0         0.00    N00.00E   NE        0.0
1   30.0    30.0        0.05    N06.40W   NW        6.4
2   60.0    60.0        0.20    N59.80W   NW       59.8
3   90.0    90.0        0.30    N51.90W   NW       51.9
4   120.0   120.0       0.28    S16.10W   SW       16.1
```

Quando tento fazer a conversão, usando o código abaixo, recebo a mensagem abaixo :

```
if df['quadrante'] == 'NE':
    df['azimute'] = df['graus'] #para o quadrante NE
elif df['quadrante'] == 'SE':
    df['azimute'] = (180 - df['graus']) #para o quadrante SE
elif df['quadrante'] == 'SW':
    df['azimute'] = (180 + df['graus']) #para o quadrante SW
elif df['quadrante'] == 'NW':
    df['azimute'] = (360 + df['graus']) #para o quadrante NW  
df
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai usar a propriedade `.loc` pra isso.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#

A estrutura básica é a seguinte:

```py
df.loc[df['nome da coluna'] condição a ser seguida, 'nome da coluna que recebe o valor'] = 'valor a ser atribuido somente se a condição for satisfeita'
```

Segue um exemplo pro seu caso específico:

#### Criando o dataframe de exemplo

```py
import pandas as pd

data = ["N00.00E",
"N06.40W",
"N59.80W",
"N51.90W",
"S16.10W",]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['DIRECAO'])

df['DIRECAO'] = df['DIRECAO'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
df['quadrante'] = df['DIRECAO'].str[0] + df['DIRECAO'].str[-1]
df['graus'] = df['DIRECAO'].str[1:-1].astype(float) 

df.to_markdown() # markdown me ajuda na hora de editar essa resposta pra imprimir a tabela abaixo
```

|  | DIRECAO | quadrante | graus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | N00.00E | NE | 0 |
| 1 | N06.40W | NW | 6.4 |
| 2 | N59.80W | NW | 59.8 |
| 3 | N51.90W | NW | 51.9 |
| 4 | S16.10W | SW | 16.1 |

#### Aplicando a propriedade `.loc`

```py
df.loc[df['quadrante'] == 'NE', 'azimute'] = df['graus']
df.loc[df['quadrante'] == 'SE', 'azimute'] = 180 - df['graus']
df.loc[df['quadrante'] == 'SW', 'azimute'] = 180 + df['graus']
df.loc[df['quadrante'] == 'NW', 'azimute'] = 360 + df['graus']

df.to_markdown()
```

|  | DIRECAO | quadrante | graus | azimute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | N00.00E | NE | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | N06.40W | NW | 6.4 | 366.4 |
| 2 | N59.80W | NW | 59.8 | 419.8 |
| 3 | N51.90W | NW | 51.9 | 411.9 |
| 4 | S16.10W | SW | 16.1 | 196.1 |